# postgresql multi-dimensional array - filtering

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a very large data set with billions of rows. I would like access certain elements within a multi-dimensional array without UNNEST if possible (query takes forever to run). please note i am using postgresql 8.2

example:

```
SELECT
 x[1:3][1:1]
FROM
(SELECT
'{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,1,8},{9,10,11,1}}'::INT[] AS X

UNION ALL

SELECT
'{{3,2,3,4},{5,6,1,8},{1,10,11,1}}'::INT[] AS X
) AS A
WHERE x[1:3][1:1] && '{1}'::INT[]
```

returns

```
{{1},{5},{9}}

{{3},{5},{1}}
```

how do I filter this to only return the first value of each array if it matches the where? (in this case 1)

I would like the output of:

```
{{1}}
{{1}}
```

thank you,

mat

Comment: And for input like `{{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2},{1,1,1,1}}` you want to get `{{1},{1}}`? IMO it is strange a bit...

Comment: yes, correct! there is a large summary of data and i would like to filter it down considerably before UNNEST. perhaps there is a different way to do this as well but i haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Is there fixed or variable dimensions of arrays?

Comment: variable dimensions

Comment: Ok, probably it will give you some ideas how to improve the performance: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=585dfc1edbbb327ffb2efd3d03df5645

Comment: PS: You definitely should to upgrade your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: thank you! i will use your example to apply to my use-case. appreciate the help! re: upgrading... haha yes... i've asked our dbas many times- it will happen soon

Comment: @Abelisto, this worked beautifully. thanks again

Comment: PS: I really not sure about PostgreSQL 8.2 but you also could to try to use GIN index, it will make your query simpler: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=647feedaefb449363f6a1363b0f6a85e

Comment: ah, unfortunately GIN doesn't work "not supported"

Comment: @Abelisto, if i wanted the array of "{{0,2,88},{1,30,21},{1,51,21}}" to output the entire array where y = 1, is that possible? so result would be {{1,30,21},{1,51,21}}

Comment: Something like `case when x[1:1][1:100] @> array[1] then x[1:1][1:100] end || case when x[2:2][1:100] @> array[1] then x[2:2][1:100] end || case when x[3:3][1:100] @> array[1] then x[3:3][1:100] end` and so on.